# why this my javascript code that validate email address when user write wrong email address run and fall in loop?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, email-validation

I have a form to register users information for signup request.
I make it by html and javascript and php.
when user write wrong email address this code run and fall in loop.

my javascript function is it:

```
function checkmail() 
{

var email = document.forms["frmreg"]["email"].value;
var filter1 = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;


if (!filter1.test(email) && email!='') 
 {

alert('your email address is invalid');

return false;
  }

}
```

and input field of email Address:

```
  <tr>

          <td>Your Email:</td>

          <td width="180" colspan="2"><input name="email" style="color: #000; font-family: Tahoma"dpieagent_iecontroltype="2"  onkeypress=""  onblur="checkmail()" /> &rArr; To recover password and notification </td>

        </tr>
```

**why this my javascript code that validate email address when user write wrong email address run and fall in loop?**

To avoid falling into the loop I defined a variable to prevent the function from being repeated

So my code changed a little bit this way:

first I defined a variable outside the function :

```
var repeatmailalert=1;

function checkmail() 
{

var email = document.forms["frmreg"]["email"].value;
var filter1 = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;


if (!filter1.test(email) && repeatmailalert==1 && email!='')
 {
    repeatmailalert++;
alert('your email address is invalid');

return false;
 }
 if(repeatmailalert>1){repeatmailalert=1;}
}
```

**What can I do to solve this problem?**

Comment: I'd try removing the line if(repeatmailalert>1){repeatmailalert=1;} and see what happens.... don't have time to implement myself...

Comment: **thanks for your reply BUT I wrote this line for returning the value to one and running again after a single stop**

Comment: When you say run and fall in the loop do you mean infinite loop?

Comment: try not use alert instead use something else. I think when you click on alert, focus is back on the HTML element and could be the reason for infinite loop

Comment: yes infinite loop
but for other fields, I have to use alert. **Who can help me solve this problem?**

Comment: but for other fields, I have to use alert.
**Who can help me solve this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(email!=''){
    if(!filter1.test(email)){
        alert('your email address is invalid');
    }else{
    //validated
    }
}
```